# FIR filter design with matlab firls() function

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, filter-design, finite-impulse-response

I have defined the following linear phase filter of order 4 (real and symmetric) in matlab:
h_d = [0.8367 -1.537 1 -1.537 0.8367]
I calculate the frequency response (for many points) and then I use firls function (which is supposed to give the least-squares solution) to find a linear phase FIR filter (5 taps) that matches the desired response. However the filter is nowhere close to h_d. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
f = [0:1/(2^14-1):1];
[a,~] = freqz([0.8367 -1.537 1 -1.537 0.8367],1,f*pi);
a=abs(a);
n = 4; % Filter order
b_lp = firls(n,f,a);
[h,w] = freqz(b_lp,1,512);
figure(1)
plot(f,20*log10(abs(a)),'-s')
hold on
plot(w/pi,20*log10(abs(h)))
```

I appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `firls()` is meant to design filters with piecewise constant magnitude responses. So in practice you use only a few frequency points and the corresponding desired magnitude values, and the function computes a linear interpolation between the given frequency points. Of course, in theory your call to `firls` is correct, but I guess that the resulting system of linear equations becomes ill-conditioned.

I wrote a function [lslevin.m](https://gist.github.com/mattdsp/fa287e57813950f4454fd3e90aa383b1), which can be used in the way you intended to use `firls`:

```
h = [0.8367 -1.537 1 -1.537 0.8367];
[H,w] = freqz(h,1,2048);    % that's more than enough frequency points
h2 = lslevin(5,w,H,ones(size(H)));
[H2,w] = freqz(h2,1,2048);
plot(w/pi,abs(H),w/pi,abs(H2),'r--')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help.